# MS Access: Replace apostrophe with empty string

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to remove apostrophes from names throughout a column. The code below runs without error but results in no changes.

```
Call ReplaceChar(tbl, col, "'", "")

Public Sub ReplaceChar(tbl, col, oldChar, newChar)

'Removes all characters that occur in value

 

    Dim result As String

    Dim param As String

 

    result = Replace("[" & tbl & "].[" & col & "]", oldChar, newChar)

    param = InStr("[" & tbl & "].[" & col & "]", oldChar)

 

    DoCmd.RunSQL "update [" & tbl & "]" & _

        "set [" & tbl & "].[" & col & "] = " & result & _

        "where " & param & " <> 0"

 

End Sub
```

I added the where statement based on another post I read to limit action to only values with string to be replaced. I also attempted to use a like statement with *'* instead of instr but that didn't work either. I tested the where instr statement and found that it always returns 0, even though the input value certainly has an apostrophe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
result = Replace("[" & tbl & "].[" & col & "]", oldChar, newChar)
```

This line replaces quote mark in the name of the table and column.

If we pass as parameters `tbl = table1`, `col = column1` result will be `[table1].[column1]`, while you expected `Replace([table1].[column1], oldChar, newChar)`

Same with the next line.

Use

```
result = "Replace([" & tbl & "].[" & col & "], """ & oldChar & """, """ & newChar & """)"
param = "InStr([" & tbl & "].[" & col & "], """ & oldChar & """)"
```

instead

Comment: This worked but I don't understand why. The positioning of the quotations is odd. If I group bracket them, I find a pair before and after my parameters and I don't know why it is parsed different than an empty string.
?"Replace(["?    & tbl &     ?"].["?   & col &    ?"], "?   ?""? & oldChar & ?""?   ?", "?   ?""?   & newChar & ?""?   ?")"?

Comment: @blupepc, if you need to use quotes inside your string, they have to be doubled like so: `"A "" quote "`. In your case it's it looks a little strange because in happens near the end of string.